# Why Fishpig www.home.com/blog redirects to home www.home.com?

Tags: wordpress, magento, magento-1.8, fishpig

I have followed the steps To integrate fishpig WordPress in to magento .

1. I have installed WordPress in /wp folder
2. I have set the home url to blog and path to wp in magento WordPress admin panel.
3. I have changed the home_url to /blog
4. I have also changed the /blog/ to /wp/ in .htaccess file.

But still when I type www.domain.com/blog it redirects to www.domain.com

No matter what I try pleas suggest the solution.